# How to loop while the condition is false instead of true? C#

Tags: c#, string, validation, integer, tryparse

I am trying to convert a string into an integer while also validating

```
string multiplierstr;
do {
    multiplierstr = Console.ReadLine();
} while (Int32.TryParse(multiplierstr, out multiplier));
```

However, it loops when the input is an integer, and I'd like it to loop when the input is a string, while still using the TryParse method. Any way to do it?

Comment: `while (!Int32.TryParse(multiplierstr, out multiplier));`

Comment: Notice the exclamation mark (not operator) in above comment.

Comment: Thanks, I've put it outside of the brackets. This question was kinda unnecessary.

Comment: @Seminix Feel free to delete it, as it´s unlikely to help any future readers.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question because others have invested time into answering it" Too late, my bad.

Comment: You could do this without the placeholder using just `while(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out multiplier));`

Comment: I've voted to close this question as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ! operator, ref [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/logical-negation-operator).

```
string multiplierstr;
do {
    multiplierstr = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!Int32.TryParse(multiplierstr, out multiplier));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your current code to run `while false` instead of `while true`:

```
string multiplierstr;
do {
    multiplierstr = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!Int32.TryParse(multiplierstr, out multiplier));
```

Notice the '!' at the start of the `while()` statement.

However, this will simply run as long as the `multplierstr`is not an Int32 which may not be exactly what you want.